# The clear_session() method of keras.backend does not clean up the fitting data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-2

I am working on a comparison of the fitting accuracy results for the different types of data quality. A "good data" is the data without any NA in the feature values. A "bad data" is the data with NA in the feature values. A "bad data" should be fixed by some value correction. As a value correction, it might be replacing NA with zero or mean value.

In my code, I am trying to perform multiple fitting procedures.

Review the simplified code:

```py
from keras import backend as K
...

xTrainGood = ... # the good version of the xTrain data 

xTrainBad = ... #  the bad version of the xTrain data

...

model = Sequential()

model.add(...)

...

historyGood = model.fit(..., xTrainGood, ...) # fitting the model with 
                                              # the original data without
                                              # NA, zeroes, or the feature mean values
```

Review the fitting accuracy plot, based on `historyGood` data:

[image]

After that, the code resets a stored the model and re-train the model with the "bad" data:

```py
K.clear_session()

historyBad = model.fit(..., xTrainBad, ...)
```

Review the fitting process results, based on `historyBad` data:

[image]

As one can notice, the initial accuracy `> 0.7`, which means the model "remembers" previous fitting.

For the comparison, this is the standalone fitting results of "bad" data:

[image]

How to reset the model to the "initial" state?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`K.clear_session()` isn't enough to reset states and ensure reproducibility. You'll also need to:

- Set (& reset) random seeds
- Reset TensorFlow default graph
- Delete previous model

Code accomplishing each below.

```py
reset_seeds()
model = make_model() # example function to instantiate model
model.fit(x_good, y_good)

del model
K.clear_session()
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()

reset_seeds()
model = make_model()
model.fit(x_bad, y_bad)
```

Note that if other variables reference the model, you should `del` them also - e.g. `model = make_model(); model2 = model` --> `del model, model2` - else they may persist. Lastly, `tf` random seeds aren't as easily reset as `random`'s or `numpy`'s, and require the graph to be cleared beforehand.

---

**Function/modules used**:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random
import keras.backend as K

def reset_seeds():
    np.random.seed(1)
    random.seed(2)
    if tf.__version__[0] == '2':
        tf.random.set_seed(3)
    else:
        tf.set_random_seed(3)
    print("RANDOM SEEDS RESET")
```

Comment: Does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when did training many models in a loop in a single file. I tried many things on Keras/TF (version 2.5), including the answers in this thread. Nothing helped apart from one thing - running one file from another file using [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), which ensures the kernel restart every single time.

In the simplest way, you can keep a training code in a single file, and access it to run your initial model or rerun the consequent model from a different file. To run one file from another simply do it in the second file:

```
run_no = [0,1,2,3]
for i in range(len()):
    subprocess.run(["ipython", "your_main_file.ipynb", str(i)])    # for jupyter
    #subprocess.run(["python3", "your_main_file.py", str(i)])      # for python
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `K.clear_session()` in the wrong way, to get a model with randomly initialized weights, you should delete the old model (using the `del` keyword), and then proceed to create a new model, and train it.

The you can use `K.clear_session()` after each fitting procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating a new model object with the same name is not enough?

```
model = make_model()
```