# Previous models affect training of new models in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

When trying to train multiple models in a row, the fitting of the previous models affects the new models, even if the new models have a different number of layers and neurons. It is a similar problem to [The clear_session() method of keras.backend does not clean up the fitting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58453793/the-clear-session-method-of-keras-backend-does-not-clean-up-the-fitting-data) but none of the solutions seem to work. After the training ends for one model and begins for the new model, the loss picks up where it left off.

```
def evaluate_network(lr,neurons,layers):
  avg_loss = []
  for i in range(1):
    global model 
    model = init_model(layers,neurons)
    #lr = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.PiecewiseConstantDecay([6000],[2e-2,5e-3])

    global optim 
    optim = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr/10000)

    # Number of training epochs
    iters = 15000

    for i in range(iters+1):
        
        loss = train_step()

    avg_loss.append(loss)
    
    reset_seeds()
    K.clear_session()
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
    del model
    del optim
    K.clear_session()
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
    reset_seeds()


  avg = sum(avg_loss)/len(avg_loss)
  print(avg)
  return -math.log(avg)
```

where reset_seed() is defined as follows:

```
def reset_seeds():
    np.random.seed(1)
    random.seed(2)
    if tf.__version__[0] == '2':
        tf.random.set_seed(3)
    else:
        tf.set_random_seed(3)
```

As can be seen in the code I pretty much tried everything but no solution works.

Comment: you have a `model` element in the `evaluate_network` function, but when you call `train_step` you are not passing the model, so I suppose that `train_step` points to a `model` object that is not the one you think it's referring to...

Comment: the model element is a global variable which is then accessed in the train_step function